# Changing text color on hover with multiline text

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I've just started coding this website for my work and I'm trying to get the text to change color when I hover over it. I have a break in my line of code and it means that the text doesn't highlight all at once? Any suggestions as to how I could do this better would be great.

```js
function updatemenu() {
  if (document.getElementById('responsive-menu').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomRightRadius = '0';
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = '5';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderRadius = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
  .column {
  flex: 20%;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:hover {
  color: #977847;
```

```html
<div class='header'>

  <div class="container">
    <span class="column">
          <a href=""> Address line one </a>
        <br>
        <a href=""> Address line two </a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a> Follow Us: </a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" ></i></a>
     </span>
    <div class="column">
      <a> second column </a>
      <a> This is second column of our grid system</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a> Third column </a>
      <a> This is third column of our grid system</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried creating different classes based on the element but because it's in a flexbox the text doesn't highlight when you just hover over it, but when you hover over the whole section.

I've tried removing the breaks in the code with pre and white-space formatting but it tends to mess up the whole header formatting. Any help is appreciated thanks. I've tried a lot of the other posted solutions here and just feel like my code must be messed up somewhere.

Comment: The JavaScript doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem you describe, and you're missing a closing `}` in the last line of your CSS.

Comment: Yeah its for a different part of the website dont stress about it haha!

Comment: My point wasn't that I was "stressed" by irrelevant code, it was a hint that irrelevant code shouldn't be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i ended up coming up with was:

```css
/*rest of code the same*/
span:hover a {
    color: #977847;
    transition: 0.3s;
    
}

span:hover i {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.3s;

}
/* rest of code same*/
```

```html
    
<!--Rest of code same-->
  <div class="container">
       <div class="column">
      <span style = "color: #977847;">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i><a href=""> Address line one </a>
          <br>
          <a href=""> Address line 2 </a>
      </span>
<!--Rest of code same-->
```

Comment: That's basically what I posted in my answer before, but in your case *each* `a` link in *each* `span` will be affected (i.e. also in other places on the page, which you might want to avoid), while using `.column:hover a`, as I did, limits the effect to`a` link inside elements that have the `column` class.

Comment: Yeah thanks thats good to know ill tackle that when i get to it though i think im  just trying to get the header navigation and footer done so i can implement them on all the pages! can always fiddle with it later thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want all the links in one column to change color when the column is hovered?

If yes, change the selector for your last CSS rule (the one defining the hover color) as follows:

```
.column:hover a {
  color: #977847;
}
```

So hovering a `.column` element changes the text color of all `a` links within it.

(note that I added some background to make the non-hovered white text visible in the snippet)

```js
function updatemenu() {
  if (document.getElementById('responsive-menu').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomRightRadius = '0';
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = '5';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.borderRadius = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.column {
  flex: 20%;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.column:hover a {
  color: #977847;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>

  <div class="container">
    <span class="column">
          <a href=""> Address line one </a>
        <br>
        <a href=""> Address line two </a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a> Follow Us: </a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f" ></i></a>
     </span>
    <div class="column">
      <a> second column </a>
      <a> This is second column of our grid system</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a> Third column </a>
      <a> This is third column of our grid system</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution i came up with was


'span:hover a {
 color: #977847;
 transition: 0.3s;
 
}

span:hover i {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 transition: 0.3s;

}'



' <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <span style = "color: #977847;">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i><a href=""> address line </a>
          <br>
          <a href=""> Address line </a>
      </span>